# BASH - Remote leading zero in IP Address

Tags: bash

I've got the following bash command, which does remove a leading zero.. but it also removes a single zero which is wrong.

```
echo $ip | sed 's/\.0\{1,2\}/\./g' | sed 's/^0\{1,2\}//'

if $ip is 192.168.1.01  the result should be 192.168.1.1
if $ip is 192.168.01.01  the result should be 192.168.1.1
if $ip is 192.168.0.01  the result should be 192.168.0.1
if $ip is 192.168.0.0  the result should be 192.168.0.0
etc
```

What I'm getting is 192.168.0.0 becomes 192.168..  or 192.168.0.01 becomes 192.168..1

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: When using bash you can replace `echo $ip |` with `<<<"$ip"`. And instead of invoking `sed` twice you can pass multiple patterns to `sed` via `-e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing now is replacing any `.0` with `.`.  This will obviously catch `1.1.0.0` as well.

This will work:

```
echo $ip | sed 's/\.0\+\([1-9]\)/\.\1/g; s/^0\+//'
```

Here we are looking for `.0[1-9]` which will only match a leading 0 that is followed by another number.  You see I used `\([1-9]\)` which saves the trailing number and is placed into the substitution with `\1`.

**EDIT**:

@tomgalpin made a good point about leading 0s in the beginning.  I don't have a smooth way of handling this with one command, so I just appended that as a separate substitution: `s/^0\+//`.

**EDIT 2**

Looks like my solution does not work with `--posix` option because of the `+`.  Replacing this with `*` will work as well though it is making redundant matches.  Also with `-E`, it is a little cleaner:

```
echo $ip | sed -E 's/\.0*([1-9])/\.\1/g; s/^0*//'
```

Comment: What about if the first octet starts with a 0 ?

Comment: What about numbers that *contain* 0? Your regex doesn’t handle `1.010.1.1`, for instance.

Comment: @KonradRudolph output: `1.10.1.1`

Comment: @KonradRudolph Maybe I'm doing something non-portable, that is the output of the command I posted on my end.  I just copy and pasted it into the terminal.   I'm using `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: @Jason Ugh, right, it works on GNU sed. I’m using macOS’s.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You make a good point though.  This does not work if I run it with the `--posix` option.  I'll add a version to the answer that does.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems to do exactly what I need :)